# Geocoder getfromlocationName crashes app

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a simple function in which one can find information from postcode. In the codes provided below if i enter a valid postcode it works fully. But problem starts when i enter a wrong postcode. I tried using statements try catch but instead of showing error the complete app crashes. I would also like to know how to restrict search only in UK. Is there any better option in finding addresses via postcode instead of using getfromlocationName function.

```
public void finder(String query){
      Geocoder geocoder;
      List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>();
      geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

      try {
          //addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(51.283973, 1.064928, 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5
          addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(query,1);
      } catch (Exception e) {

          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fail " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

      String street = addresses.get(0).getThoroughfare();
      Log.i("I0",street);


      String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
      Log.i("I1",city);

      String county = addresses.get(0).getSubAdminArea();
      Log.i("I2",county);

      String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
      Log.i("I3",country);
      String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
      Log.i("I4",postalCode);

      display.setText(street + "\n" + city + "\n" + country + "\n" + postalCode  ); }
```

error is

```
07-13 21:15:26.717 10744-10744/com.example.mandeep.testing I/i1: ct3456
07-13 21:15:26.856 10744-10744/com.example.mandeep.testing D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-13 21:15:26.857 10744-10744/com.example.mandeep.testing E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.mandeep.testing, PID: 10744
                                                                             java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
                                                                                 at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                                                 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                                                                                 at com.example.mandeep.testing.MainActivity.finder(MainActivity.java:85)
                                                                                 at com.example.mandeep.testing.MainActivity$1.onQueryTextSubmit(MainActivity.java:47)
                                                                                 at android.widget.SearchView.onSubmitQuery(SearchView.java:1197)
                                                                                 at android.widget.SearchView.access$900(SearchView.java:92)
                                                                                 at android.widget.SearchView$8.onEditorAction(SearchView.java:1175)
                                                                                 at android.widget.TextView.onEditorAction(TextView.java:4473)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.performEditorAction(EditableInputConnection.java:139)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:304)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5219)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
07-13 21:15:26.878 10744-10744/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10744 SIG: 9
```

I tried

```
if(addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {

          String street = addresses.get(0).getThoroughfare();
          Log.i("I0", street);


          String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
          Log.i("I1", city);

          String county = addresses.get(0).getSubAdminArea();
          Log.i("I2", county);

          String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
          Log.i("I3", country);
          String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
          Log.i("I4", postalCode);

          display.setText(street + "\n" + city + "\n" + country + "\n" + postalCode);
      }
      else{
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Results Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
```

still the same problem.

I have edited the code now

```
public void finder(String query){
      Geocoder geocoder;
      List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>();
      geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

      try {
          //addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(51.283973, 1.064928, 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5
          addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(query,1);
      } catch (Exception e) {

          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fail " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

      Log.i("yes",addresses.size() + "");

      if(addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
          Log.i("yes","checked");

          String street = addresses.get(0).getThoroughfare();
          Log.i("I0", street);


          String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
          Log.i("I1", city);

          String county = addresses.get(0).getSubAdminArea();
          Log.i("I2", county);

          String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
          Log.i("I3", country);
          String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
          Log.i("I4", postalCode);

          display.setText(street + "\n" + city + "\n" + country + "\n" + postalCode);
      }
      else{
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Results Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }


  }
```

and now the error is

```
07-13 22:21:02.782 32088-32088/com.example.mandeep.testing I/i1: ct28dx
07-13 22:21:02.942 32088-32088/com.example.mandeep.testing I/yes: 1
07-13 22:21:02.942 32088-32088/com.example.mandeep.testing I/yes: checked
07-13 22:21:02.942 32088-32088/com.example.mandeep.testing D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-13 22:21:02.944 32088-32088/com.example.mandeep.testing E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.mandeep.testing, PID: 32088
                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
                                                                                 at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
                                                                                 at android.util.Log.i(Log.java:160)
                                                                                 at com.example.mandeep.testing.MainActivity.finder(MainActivity.java:93)
                                                                                 at com.example.mandeep.testing.MainActivity$1.onQueryTextSubmit(MainActivity.java:52)
                                                                                 at android.widget.SearchView.onSubmitQuery(SearchView.java:1197)
                                                                                 at android.widget.SearchView.access$900(SearchView.java:92)
                                                                                 at android.widget.SearchView$8.onEditorAction(SearchView.java:1175)
                                                                                 at android.widget.TextView.onEditorAction(TextView.java:4473)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.performEditorAction(EditableInputConnection.java:139)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:304)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5219)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
07-13 22:21:02.973 32088-32088/com.example.mandeep.testing I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 32088 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check your array's size first

```
if(addresses.size() > 0){
    String street = addresses.get(0).getThoroughfare();
          Log.i("I0",street);


          String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
          Log.i("I1",city);

          String county = addresses.get(0).getSubAdminArea();
          Log.i("I2",county);

          String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
          Log.i("I3",country);
          String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
          Log.i("I4",postalCode);

          display.setText(street + "\n" + city + "\n" + country + "\n" + postalCode  ); 
}
```

you are tring to get data from index 0 but your list is empty.

Comment: I tried still the same problem please see above i have added codes

Comment: first, tell me is your app is crashing after this check?

Comment: How can i know that ?

Comment: what ur are passing in **query**

Comment: yes it is checking the condition because i passed this line Log.i("yes","checked"); immediately after the condition and b4 it crashes it shows checked after wrong postcode entered.

Comment: do you know how to debug Android apps ?

Comment: I am passing a string in query

Comment: Check out this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKCvtNj8C0s and debug your app this will help you find the cause of crashes easily. according to me you are getting nothing from **geocoder.getFromLocationName(query,1);**

Comment: I am sorry to say but i am getting some sort of return which is confirmed with new code and new error result above.

Comment: you are using **Log.i** without a message (i.e. null)  in MainActivity on line number 93

Comment: Will it be possible you copy and paste it here as it is difficult for me to find it. Thank u

Comment: No need its working fully now thank u very much. I know the problem nw the problem was with log function as street was giving null so Log function was not getting string. i tried it with commenting all log functions and now the app does not crash. Thank you very much .

Answer (score 0):

This line `geocoder.getFromLocationName(query,1);` returned an empty List. It could be because no matches were found or there is no backend service available (according to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html). You should check if `addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0` is true before performing operations with your list.

Comment: I tried still the same problem please see above i have added codes

Comment: Can I see the error logs? If they are the same as before, please send this line 'at com.example.mandeep.testing.MainActivity.finder(MainActivity.java:85)' or whichever line it is after your code change.

Comment: can you send this line MainActivity‌​.java:85? The line in MainActivity where it crashes.

Comment: i have added new codes and error above please check

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, don't assume `Geocoder.getFromLocationName()` always returns results. It can return an empty array.

Also:

- `Address.getLocality()`, `Address.getAdminArea()` etc. *can* return null. You have to check for this.
- Don't assume the number of lines in `Address.getAddressLine(int)`. Check how many lines are *actually* returned with `Address.getMaxAddressLineIndex()`.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, then I declared a variable with default value at the beginning, so if there's an answer to the request you overwrite the variable if not the default value will be returned. In that case you can simply write "Something doesn't work correctly, please try again" or something like that.

```
   fun getCountryCodeFromName(locationName: String = "California"): String {
    var postalCode:String = "00000"
    try {
        if (find(locationName).size !=0)
           countryCode = cityNameReq(locationName)[0].postalCode

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        resultMessage = Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.catch_me)
        Log.e(TAG, resultMessage, e)
    }

    return postalCode
}
```

Basically

```
                         `var postalCode:String = "00000"`
```

will be returned if the program doesn't go to the try block and catches an exception.

and if the request is successful the postalCode gets the new value assigned to it as you see in this line:

```
      countryCode = cityNameReq(locationName)[0].postalCode
```

PS: It's late for the questioner, I know, but I send my answer for those who still might have this problem and are looking for an answer: